# How to remove duplicate consecutive text in R separated by :

Tags: r

**the data set looks like**

```
  id  agent    final_col
1  1   A:A         A
2  1   A:A         A
3  2     B         B
4  3     C         C
5  4 A:C:C       A:C
6  4 A:C:C       A:C
7  4 A:C:C       A:C
```

How can I remove duplicate entries, to have a clean column like the `final_col` in R?

Comment: Do you want to remove only duplicates, or duplicate consecutives? Should A:C:A become A:C or A:C:A? In the second case, you could do `sapply(agent, function(x){y=unlist(strsplit(x,':'));paste(y[cumsum(rle(y)$length)],collapse=":")})`

Comment: remove duplicates, consecutive or not consecutive is not relevant, I believe I need to reword the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `gsub` and a regular expression

```
gsub("\\b(\\w+)(\\:\\1)+\\b", "\\1", DAT$agent)
[1] "A"   "A"   "B"   "C"   "A:C" "A:C" "A:C"
```

## Your Data

```
DAT = read.table(text="  id  agent    final_col
1  1   A:A         A
2  1   A:A         A
3  2     B         B
4  3     C         C
5  4 A:C:C       A:C
6  4 A:C:C       A:C
7  4 A:C:C       A:C",
header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's just generate a new column based on `df$agent`

```
df$final_col <- sapply(df$agent, function(txt){ 
    paste(unique(unlist(strsplit(txt, ":"))), collapse=":")
})
```

For each element we split by `:`, select unique elements, and again put them together.

Comment: is `strsplit` from base r, for some reason, i am having trouble reproducing, it says Error in strsplit non character argument

Comment: @ImranAli because `df$agent` is factor, wrap it with `as.character(df$agent)`.